# Broken file type associations after running update-mime-database

Tags: gnome, mime-type, file-association, file-type

After running `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` my gnome doesn't recognize any file types anymore.  In Nautilus all files are now `text/plain type` and all now open with gedit by default.  Gnome-commander does the same.

I guess that it's not that file associations are broken but rather file type recognition problem.

Tried to (not in that order):

- rerun `update-mime-database` several times
- reinstal package `gnome-mime-data`
- delete `~/.local/share/applications/*`
- logout and login many times
- reboot

Nothing helped so far.

My system:

> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx)
>   Gnome 2.30.2

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and I solved it reinstalling the shared-mime-info package with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall shared-mime-info
```

Comment: Still useful in Ubuntu 22.04, but you'll probably need to reboot immediately after this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **[assoGiate](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/) program** - a file types editor. To install it from [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), use next command:

```
sudo apt-get install assogiate
```

[image: assoGiate]

Comment: Done that already.  File types database is in place and seems to be correct.

Comment: Some additional details.

`$ file --mime-type -k 144408743.jpg
144408743.jpg: image/jpeg
$ xdg-mime query filetype 144408743.jpg
application/octet-stream
$ mimetype --all --debug 144408743.jpg
> Data dirs are: /home/alomaka/.local/share, /usr/share/gnome, /usr/local/share, /usr/share
> Checking inode type
> Checking globs for basename '144408743.jpg'
> Checking for extension '.jpg'
> Checking all magic rules
> File exists, trying default method
> First 10 bytes of the file contain control chars
144408743.jpg: application/octet-stream
$`

Comment: It looks like my GNOME doesn't look at system-wide file types database. Only in my personal `~/.local/share/mime`.

Answer (score 0):

Running `update-mime-database` as root removes 'other' access from some mime database files. Running

```
chmod -R o+r /usr/share/mime
```

afterwards will fix this up.