# Sometimes video and image files are not opened/played in MPV and Gwenview

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, dolphin, mpv-media-player, gwenview

In Kubuntu 22.04 I am plagued by this occurrence:

- from time to time when I double-click a video file in Dolphin it will not start at all in its associated application MPV; if I "open with" a different application (SMPlayer, VLC) the file opens
- the same happens with image files and Gwenview
- if I restart Dolphin this is fixed
- but it happens rather often

Is there some trick to fix this buggy behavior?

---

(This was fixed in 22.10 and is the reason why I have given up LTS for now.)

Comment: Seems like an issue with your mime database/ applications directory. Maybe try the answer suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/292728/broken-file-type-associations-after-running-update-mime-database

Comment: @MaximilianBallard - I hope your comment helps in the future. It comes too late for me here, I have meanwhile went to 22.10, and I don't have this problem.